# How can I prevent multiple setTimeout 's from being set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, timeout, settimeout

I have a javascript object that represents a processing video. As the video is processing, I send a request to the server every `5000` milliseconds, and once it is processed, it *should* unbind itself, and complete. The trouble is that every time it checks the server to see if it's complete, it re-renders an instance of itself, and binds an additional `5000` millisecond timeout. Consequentially an exponential loop occurs, and will eventually crash the browser.

I have a loop error occurring because of this event handler :

```
initialize: function() {
  this.on('all', this.reset_auto_refresh, this);
  this.auto_refresh();
},
```

Once this `initialize()` method is cast, it binds `reset_auto_refresh` and runs `auto_refresh` .

```
auto_refresh: function(timeout) {
  if(this.is_processing()) {
    if(!timeout) timeout = 5000;
    var callback = _.bind(function() {
      this._timer = null;
      this.fetch({error: _.bind(function() { this.reset_auto_refresh(15000); }, this)});
      this.auto_refresh();
    }, this);
    this._timer = setTimeout(callback, timeout);
  }
},
reset_auto_refresh: function(timeout) {
  if(this._timer) clearTimeout(this._timer);
  this.auto_refresh(timeout);
}
```

Because every time it instantiates, it's technically a different object, I havn't figured out a way for *any* instance to share a single `._timer`, and therefore, they keep adding on new setTimeout's even though one already exists and is running.

Would anyone know a best practice, or a way to prevent multiple instances setting a setTimeout here?